# Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use Spring and my problem is that I have a code snippet like this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
private void testMethod1() {
    ...

    try {
        testMethod2();
    } catch (CustomException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ...
}
```

and if testMethod2 throws a CustomException I get the following Exception:

> Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

I tried

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, noRollbackFor = CustomException.class)
    private void testMethod1() {}
```

or

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = CustomException.class)
        private void testMethod1() {}
```

but it does not work. Could somebody help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: If the code snippet you are showing accurately reflects your code, then it makes sense that your transactional handling is not correct. You need `@Transactional` does not work on `private` methods, neither does it work when the method is invoked from inside the same class. Please post some more code showing how you are calling the method